# Python scipy find_simplex freezes

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

I am trying to use scipy.spatial.Delaunay to implement "Fast dynamic grid deformation based on Delaunay graph mapping":

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999105002809

I am trying to use find_simplex to find which points are in which triangle/tet but for some reason the process freezes for one particular point.

I have decomposed the entire domain so each point should be within one triangle/tet.

The points are a large set of coordinates for a mesh around a wing segment. The points on the surface of the wing segment and the farfield make up the vertices. The segment of code that is causing me problems is below:

```
 for j in xrange(len(points[:,0])):
      simp = tri.find_simplex(points[j,:3]) <<freezes here at j=213877
      vert = tri.vertices[simp]
```

I am using:
SciPy 0.9.0 and
Python 2.6.5

I understand that this is limited info as I have not made the data set available but does anyone have any idea what is causing this or perhaps suggest a work-around?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is most likely to just upgrade to a more recent Scipy version.

Comment: I was worried that this would be the solution.

I am on a cluster and don't have admin priviledges so I will attempt to run a newer scipy from my home directrory.

Comment: The latest version does not freeze.